# C - Reading from a file

Tags: c, file, fgetc

I have a text file containing the following:

```
ANT. Small insect,  
sometimes has wings on its back.

BEAR. Large beast.
```

I have a c program:

```
int main(void)
{
   FILE *fp;
   int c;

   fp = fopen("myfile.txt","r");
   if(fp == NULL) 
   {
      perror("Error in opening file");
      return(-1);
   } do {
      c = fgetc(fp);
      if(feof(fp))
         break ;
    if (c != '\n')
        printf("%c", c);
   }while(1);

   fclose(fp);
}
```

However it only prints:

```
BEAR. Large beast.
```

I want it to print:

```
ANT. Small insect, sometimes has wings on its back.  
BEAR. Large beast.
```

Comment: use `fscanf()` to make it easy or `fgets()`

Comment: I doubt that's the only output you get, if the contents of the file is as you say. The loop should print every character from the file *except* newlines, so all the contents should be on a single line.

Comment: Also, the standard way to do a loop like yours would more like `while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) { printf("%c", c); }`

Comment: The output should be correct...you should check your output once more or the input file

Comment: works fine on my compiler except there is no newline but everything else is as expected

Comment: Still not working for me

Comment: Slightly altered to read from `stdin` instead, [it works (almost) as expected](http://ideone.com/HXSgPy).

Comment: Figured it out I made the text file in windows and transferred to my linux. Made a new file just on my linux, and it works. Strange

Comment: @JayJay5 newline charcter in windows is different from linux...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/*Everything looks find in your code. in my machine it is working fine . I have only added a if condition to print the contents same as the file thats it .. */

#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   FILE *fp;
   int c;

   fp = fopen("rabi.txt","r");
   if(fp == NULL)
   {
      perror("Error in opening file");
      return(-1);
   } do {
      c = fgetc(fp);
      if(feof(fp))
         break ;

        printf("%c", c);

        printf ("\n");
   }while(1);
printf ("\n");
   fclose(fp);
}


o/p-->
rabi@rabi-VirtualBox:~/rabi/c$ gcc 11.c 
rabi@rabi-VirtualBox:~/rabi/c$ ./a.out 
ANT. Small insect,
sometimes has wings on its back.

BEAR. Large beast.
```

Comment: could have omitted the previous if statement instead of writing another if

Answer (score 2):

Text files created on DOS/Windows machines have different line endings than files created on Unix/Linux. DOS uses carriage return and line feed ("\r\n") as a line ending, which Unix uses just line feed ("\n"). You need to be careful about transferring files between Windows machines and Unix machines to make sure the line endings are translated properly.

**[Read More](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~krueger/csc209h/tut/line-endings.html)**